# Share image to twitter in Android without native app

Tags: android, twitter

I want to share image and text to twitter without native app. I have installed fabric plugin that twitter recommended and used this code for sharing:

```
TweetComposer.Builder builder = new TweetComposer.Builder(this)
 .text("just setting up my Fabric.")
 .image(myImageUri);
builder.show();
```

[In the event that the Twitter app is not installed, TweetComposer will create an intent to interact with the Twitter.com in a browser. The browser ignores a specified image.](https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/compose-tweets.html) Is it possible to send image if native app is not installed?

Comment: Have you considered using Twitter4j? http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html#oauth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many time of searching I finally choose Twitter4j library for this purpose.

Also [this](https://github.com/learnNcode/DemoTwitterImagePost) tutorial was very helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the Tutorial.